# MSDTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator) Stops working. Error code -1073737669

Tags: service, msdtc

I cannot start Distributed Transaction Coordinator service. 
It stoped to work few days ago.

When I am trying to start service:

[image]

[image]

Registry properties:

[image]

RPC (For a test values was changed here to oposite and back - without any results ):

[image]

```
Windows logs\application logs:

53283
    A MS DTC component has encountered an internal error. The process is being terminated. Error Specifics: DtcSystemShutdown (d:\w7rtm\com\complus\dtc\dtc\msdtc\src\msdtc.cpp@2539): Shutting down with an error

4111
    The MS DTC service is stopping.

4102
    DTC Security Configuration values (OFF = 0 and ON = 1):  Network Administration of Transactions = 1,
      Network Clients = 1,
       Inbound Distributed Transactions using Native MSDTC Protocol = 1,
          Outbound Distributed Transactions using Native MSDTC Protocol = 1,
       Transaction Internet Protocol (TIP) = 0,
       XA Transactions = 1,
       SNA LU 6.2 Transactions = 1

    Could not initialize the MS DTC Transaction Manager.

    4356

    Failed to initialize the MS DTC Communication Manager.  Error Specifics: hr = 0x80070057, d:\w7rtm\com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\ccm.cpp:2117, CmdLine: C:\Windows\System32\msdtc.exe, Pid: 5332

4358
    The MS DTC Connection Manager is unable to register with RPC to use one of LRPC, TCP/IP, or UDP/IP. Please ensure that RPC is configured properly. If "ServerTcpPort" registry key is configured(DWORD value under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSDTC for local DTC instance or under cluster hive for clustered DTC instance), please verify if the configured port is valid and the port is not already in use by a different component. Error Specifics:hr = 0x80070057, d:\w7rtm\com\complus\dtc\dtc\cm\src\iomgrsrv.cpp:2523, CmdLine: C:\Windows\System32\msdtc.exe, Pid: 5332

4156

    String message: RPC raised an exception with a return code RPC_S_INVALIDA_ARG..

I found that we can use -resetlog command. But this doesnot resolving my problem:
```

[image]
**Firewall is disabled.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to delete key HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Rpc\Internet from registry.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this issue, I had to copy the log file (I accidentally deleted) to the location specified by the Local DTC Log information location.